# Don't want preloaded track in Soundcloud widget player

Tags: html, soundcloud, web-widget

Recently I added soundcloud widget player in one of my website. Now I am using the website buttons to pass the track URLs in widget.

What I want to do is when widget iframe is loading first time a track is needed to show the player. I just want empty player. Below is the iframe code:

```
<iframe id="soundcloud_widget"
  src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/107739199&amp;color=000000&amp;inverse=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_user=true;hide_related=true;show_comments=false;show_reposts=false;show_playcount=false;start_track=1000000"
  frameborder="no" >
</iframe>
```

Here one have to pass the URL. How can I just load an empty soundcloud widget player?

[SoundCloud Widget Player API link](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#params).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'empty' player, since it's not much use to anyone. If you have a particular case for something like that, why not create a placeholder image for the widget and swap it out when the right time comes?

Comment: Yeah now I am hiding the player at startup and when user will click. It will slide open. Thanks for your guidance. :)